# The remote end hung up unexpectedly error when code commit to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to commit Flutter code to feature branch dev-irshad. It is the same branch where I have been committing code and it uploads correctly but its not uploading to bitbucket this time.
Can someone suggest whats going on here?
[image: Bitbucket commit error]

Comment: Look a few lines higher. I'd cut and paste the error message that you *should* have looked at, but I can't, because you used an image instead of text. See also [ask].